# some error in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1054

now I try this query in PhpMyAdmin to update wp_postmeta with value form wp_posts:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta
SET meta_value = (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM wp_posts) 
WHERE EXISTS (select 1 
              from wp_posts 
              join articles on wp_posts.post_name=articles.image)
    AND (wp_posts.post_type='attachment') 
    AND (wp_postmeta.meta_key='_thumbnail_id' )
```

but given me that error: #1054 - Unknown column 'wp_posts.post_type' in 'where clause' !

i try to change it without benefit, anyone can help?

Comment: After you fix the 1054 error, this is going to error on the meta_value = because the subquery can return more than one row.

Answer (score 1):

```
AND (wp_posts.post_type='attachment')
```

I think the real issue here, is that the only place you're referencing wp_posts is in your EXISTS and SET subqueries.  That part of the WHERE clause (quoted above) is outside the scope of your subqueries and doesn't know about it.

Unless you meant for your EXISTS subquery to look like this:

```
(select 1 
 from wp_posts 
 join articles on wp_posts.post_name=articles.image
 WHERE wp_posts.post_type='attachment')
```

In this case, wp_posts is referenced in the same set of parens and is syntactically correct.  Since this probably won't give you what you're after, try this instead:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta
INNER JOIN wp_posts ON wp_posts.id = wp_postmeta.post_id
SET meta_value = (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM wp_posts WHERE [some condition]) 
WHERE EXISTS (select 1 
          from wp_posts 
          join articles on wp_posts.post_name=articles.image)
    AND (wp_posts.post_type='attachment') 
    AND (wp_postmeta.meta_key='_thumbnail_id' )
```

Note #1: I'm making an assumption that your wp_postmeta table has a post_id field that corresponds to id on wp_posts.

Note #2: As OMG Ponies stated...

```
SET meta_value = (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM wp_posts)
```

This line will most-likely throw an error for returning multiple values where only 1 is expected.  Note that I've added a "WHERE [some condition]" above.  You'll want to add your own WHERE clause here.  And it should be something that limits the subquery result to only one result.

Comment: You're on the right track, but the query needs to join to wp_posts

Answer (score 0):

You should move your right parenthesis in:

```
(SELECT DISTINCT id FROM wp_posts)
```

to the end of the statement.

Comment: What's the error now? Can you give some info on the columns of your wp_posts and wp_postmeta tables?